# How to find neighbours with the same value in 2-D array in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix with dimensions NxN, E.g. in this case 5x5:

```
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 0
```

and I want to get all the neighbours with the same value like the element at position (3,3), and also to get neighbours of the neighbours with same value, etc. The constraint is that I can not use recursion, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The algorithm you're looking for is a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), which can be implemented with a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) using a queue.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using recursion?

Comment: @miki1307 : Do you already have a recursive algorithm?  if so adapt it as per https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418776/How-to-replace-recursive-functions-using-stack-and

Answer (score 0):

This might be the simplest solution.
Assuming that diagonals aren't considered as neighbours.

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
    if (i > 0  &&  tab[i][j] == tab[i-1][j]) {
      // same value
    }
    if (i < N-1  &&  tab[i][j] == tab[i+1][j]) {
      // same value
    }
    if (j > 0  &&  tab[i][j] == tab[i][j-1]) {
      // same value
    }
    if (j < N-1  &&  tab[i][j] == tab[i][j+1]) {
      // same value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to iterate from the begininng of matrix. I need to eneter coordinates, E.g. (3,3) and based on that I need to find all the neighbours of the element at (3,3) with the same value, and the neighbours of those neighbours with the same value etc.

Comment: @mili1307 then do that?? What is the problem?